# PHP, read line by line, not working

Tags: php, sql, json, mysqli, bigdata

I have this code. The idea with it, is that i reads a big(very big: 300mb) JSON file, line by line and set the JSON data into an SQL table. But the same line of JSON data gets inserted more than once, and after the PHP script has been through all lines, it just starts over.

There is 200268 objects in the JSON file, seperated in lines

Here is my code:

example.php:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Licensed under Creative Commons 3.0 Attribution
 * Copyright Adam Wulf 2013
 */

include("config-sample.php");
include("include.classloader.php");

$classLoader->addToClasspath(ROOT);


$mysql = new MySQLConn(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASS);

$db = new JSONtoMYSQL($mysql);


$handle = fopen("programoversigter.json", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($linne = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

        $db->save(json_decode($linne)->_source, "igen");
        print($iasd . " ");
        $iasd = $iasd++;
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "assscsad";
}
die();
?>
```

include.classloader.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Licensed under Creative Commons 3.0 Attribution
 * Copyright Adam Wulf 2013
 */
class ClassLoader{
    protected $classpath;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->classpath = array();
    }

    public function addToClasspath($dir){
        if(is_dir($dir)){
            $this->classpath[] = $dir;
        }else{
            throw new Exception("cannot find directory: $dir");
        }
    }

    public function load($classname){
        $ok = false;
        for($i=0;$i<count($this->classpath);$i++){
            $path = $this->classpath[$i];
/*          echo "load recur \"" . $path . "\";//<br>\n"; */
            $ok = $ok || $this->load_recursive($path, $classname);
        }
        return $ok;
    }

    protected function load_recursive($classpath, $classname){
        $theList = array();
        $ret = false;
        if ($handle = opendir($classpath)) {
            while (false != ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                    if(is_dir($classpath . $file)){
                        $ret = $ret || $this->load_recursive($classpath . $file . "/", $classname);
                    }else{
                        if($file == "class.$classname.php"){
                            include_once $classpath . $file;
                            $ret = true;
/*                          echo "include_once \"" . $classpath . $file . "\";//<br>\n"; */
                        }else
                        if($file == "class.Boolean.$classname.php"){
                            include_once $classpath . $file;
                            $ret = true;
/*                          echo "include_once \"" . $classpath . $file . "\";//<br>\n"; */
                        }else
                        if($file == "interface.$classname.php"){
                            include_once $classpath . $file;
                            $ret = true;
/*                          echo "include_once \"" . $classpath . $file . "\";//<br>\n"; */
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        closedir($handle);
        unset($handle);
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    public function loadTestFiles(GroupTest $g){
        foreach($this->classpath as $c){
            $this->loadTestFilesHelper($g, $c);
        }
    }

    protected function loadTestFilesHelper(GroupTest $g, $classpath){
        $theList = array();
        if ($handle = opendir($classpath)) {
            while (false != ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                    if(is_dir($classpath . $file)){
                        $this->loadTestFilesHelper($g, $classpath . $file . "/");
                    }else{
                        if(strpos($file, "test.class.") === 0 &&
                        strpos($file, ".php") == strlen($file)-4){
                            $g->addTestFile($classpath . $file);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        closedir($handle);
        unset($handle);
        }

    }
  }

  class ClassLoaderToString extends ClassLoader{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function load_recursive($classpath, $classname){
        $theList = array();
        $ret = false;
        if ($handle = opendir($classpath)) {
            while (false != ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                    if(is_dir($classpath . $file)){
                        $this->load_recursive($classpath . $file . "/", $classname);
                    }else{
                        if($file == "class.$classname.php"){
                            include_once $classpath . $file;
                            $this->printClass($classpath, $file);
                            $ret = true;
                        }else
                        if($file == "class.Boolean.$classname.php"){
                            include_once $classpath . $file;
                            $this->printClass($classpath, $file);
                            $ret = true;
                        }else
                        if($file == "interface.$classname.php"){
                            include_once $classpath . $file;
                            $this->printClass($classpath, $file);
                            $ret = true;
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
        unset($handle);
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    protected function printClass($classpath, $file){
        if(strpos($classpath, ROOT) === 0){
            $classpath = substr($classpath, strlen(ROOT));
            echo "include_once(ROOT . \"" . $classpath . $file . "\");\n";
        }else{
            echo "include_once(\"" . $classpath . $file . "\");\n";
        }
    }
  }  


  function milestone_autoload($classname){
    global $classLoader;
//  global $control;
//  $str = "classname: ";
//  $str .= $classname;
//  $str .= "\n";
//  if(is_object($control) && !is_int(stripos($classname, "mysql"))){
//      $control->getModel()->getLogger()->log($control->getModel(), ALogger::$HIGH, $str);
//  }
    try{
        $ok = $classLoader->load($classname);
//      $str .= ":" . $ok;
//      if(is_object($control) && !is_int(stripos($classname, "mysql"))){
//          $control->getModel()->getLogger()->log($control->getModel(), ALogger::$HIGH, $str);
//      }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        $model->getLogger()->log($model, ALogger::$HIGH, print_r($e, true));
    }
  }

spl_autoload_register('milestone_autoload');

    $classLoader = new ClassLoader();
?>
```

Comment: @RyanVincent, why not put your response as an answer so we can upvote it?

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would cause it to insert a line multiple times, or restart when it reaches the end of the file. Something must be calling the script repeatedly.

Comment: Enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and check for errors.

Comment: It's a array, with 200268 objects. But instead of being seperated by "," it is seperated by a new line. https://lego-ev3.com/sandbox/programoversigter.json